# How to create a function that applies a function to the inputs of another function in Python?

Tags: python, functional-programming, currying

I'm looking for a nice functional way to do the following:

```
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

def neg(x):
    return -x

def c(x, y):
    # Apply neg to inputs for add
    _x = neg(x)
    _y = neg(y)

    return add(_x, _y)

neg_sum = c(2, 2)   # -4
```

It seems related to currying, but all of the examples I can find use functions that only have one input variable. I would like something that looks like this:

```
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

def neg(x):
    return -x

c = apply(neg, add)
neg_sum = c(2, 2)   # -4
```

Comment: You want `apply(g, f)` to create a new function `c` that applies function `g` to all its arguments, then passes the results to function `f`. This assumes that functions `c` and `f` accept the same number of arguments (possibly multiple) and that both `c` and `f` return a single value. Is that right? I feel like there could be some other cases where you want to construct `f(g(h(x)), g(h(y)))` or `h(f(g(x), g(y)))`, and this may not have enough symmetry for that. Or maybe it does, if you just call `apply` multiple times, sometimes with single-argument functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a fairly direct way to do it:

```
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

def neg(x):
    return -x

def apply(g, f):
    # h is a function that returns
    # f(g(arg1), g(arg2), ...)
    def h(*args):
        return f(*map(g, args))
    return h

# or this:
# def apply(g, f):
#    return lambda *args: f(*map(g, args))

c = apply(neg, add)
neg_sum = c(2, 2)   # -4
```

Note that when you use `*myvar` as an argument in a function definition, `myvar` becomes a list of all non-keyword arguments that are received. And if you call a function with `*expression` as an argument, then all the items in `expression` are unpacked and sent as separate arguments to the function. I use these two behaviors to make `h` accept an unknown list of arguments, then apply function `g` to each one (with `map`), then pass all of them as arguments to `f`.

Comment: Elaborating on your answer : how would you code a compose function thaht would work for both `add_neg = compose(add, neg)` and `neg_add = compose(neg,add)` ?

Answer (score 0):

A different approach, depending on how extensible you need this to be, is to create an object which implements your operator methods, which each return the same object, allowing you to chain operators together in arbitrary orders.

If you can cope with it always returning a list, you might be able to make it work.

```
class mathifier:

    def __init__(self,values):
        self.values = values

    def neg(self):
        self.values = [-value for value in self.values]
        return self

    def add(self):
        self.values = [sum(self.values)]
        return self
         
print (mathifier([2,3]).neg().add().values)
```

And you can still get your named function for any set of chained functions:

```
neg_add = lambda x : mathifier(x).neg().add()

print(neg_add([2,3]).values)
```

Answer (score 0):

From Matthias Fripp's answer, I asked myself  : I'd like to compose `add` and `neg` both ways : `add_neg(*args)` and `neg_add(*args)`. This requires hacking Matthias suggestion a bit. The idea is to get some hint on the arity (number of args) of the functions to compose. This information is obtained with a bit of introspection, thanks to `inspect` module. With this in mind, we adapt the way args are passed through the chain of funcs. The main assumption here is that we deal with real functions, in the mathematical sense, i.e. functions returning ONE float, and taking at least one argument.

```py
from functools import reduce
from inspect import getfullargspec


def arity_one(func):
    spec = getfullargspec(func)
    return len(spec[0])==1 and spec[1] is None

def add(*args):
    return reduce(lambda x,y:x+y, args, 0)

def neg(x):
    return -x

def compose(fun1,fun2):
    def comp(*args):
        if arity_one(fun2): return fun1(*(map( fun2, args)))
        else: return fun1(fun2(*args))
    return comp


neg_add = compose(neg, add)
add_neg = compose(add, neg)

print(f"-2+(-3) = {add_neg(2, 3)}")
print(f"-(2+3) = {neg_add(2, 3)}")
```

The solution is still very adhoc...